# How can i combine two <head> tags in an HTML document using php?

Tags: html

I have a PHP website, where it contains `header.php` in the `includes`. And I include this `header.php` in many other .php pages of my website. The `header.php` already contains  `<head>` tags which are necessary for every page. And I want to add different meta title and description for each page separately.

So when the `index.php` loads it have two  tags. And when I test the website with lighthouse Audit in Chrome. My SEO say no metadata found in the HTML document.

So please help me to combine those two  tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to remove the `<head>` tags from `header.php`, or put variables in it and set them before you include it.

So, `header.php` would look like this:

```
<head>
    echo "<title>".$page_title."</title>";
    echo "<meta name='description' content='".$meta_desc."' >";

    ...existing code...
</head>
```

and an outer file would look like this (for example):

```
$page_title = "About Page";
$meta_desc = "A page explaining the purpose of the site";

include "header.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Includes have access to all variables defined before the file is included.
So you can set variables for the title and description in the pages where you want to use differing ones and then access them in the included file. Roughly:

```
$title = "Some page title";
$desc = "Page description";
include 'header.php'
```

Then, in header.php

```
if($title) {
   // output this variable as the page title
} else {
   // no new title supplied so use the default one
}

// repeat for description
```